# Javascript/Jquery pop-up window in Asp.Net MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Below I have a "button" (just a span with an icon) that creates a pop-up view of a div in my application to allow users to compare information in seperate windows.

However, I get and Asp.Net Error as follows:

******Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /Home/[object Object]******

Does anyone have an Idea of why this is happending? Below is my code:

```
<div class="module_actions">
<div class="actions">
<span class="icon-expand2 pop-out"></span>
</div>       
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {

    var Clone =
    $(".pop-out").click(function () {
        $(this).parents(".module").clone().appendTo("#NewWindow");
    });

   $(".pop-out").click(function popitup(url) {

       LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width - 400) / 1 : 0;
       TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height - 700) / 1 : 0;
       var sheight = (screen.height) * 0.5;
       var swidth = (screen.width) * 0.5;

       settings = 'height=' + sheight + ',width=' + swidth + ',top=' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menu=no, directories=no,titlebar=no,location=no,addressbar=no'

       newwindow = window.open(url, '/Index', settings);
       if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
       return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: what do you get on the line window.open if you replace the ',' with +?

Comment: If I add url + "Index" + setting  i get

Requested URL: /Home/[object Object]/Indexheight=540,width=960,top=380,left=1520,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menu=no, directories=no,titlebar=no,location=no,addressbar=no

If I add url + "Index" , setting 
/Home/[object Object]/Index

Comment: Your code above will set the title of the window to be '/Index'  I'm assuming that's what you want for the title... if that is supposed to be appended to the url then you should put a + there... however... you still need to fix the url to concatenate a valid url instead of the javascript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above will set the title of the window to be '/Index'.  If you wanted that to be part of the URL you'll need to change that to a + to concatenate it to the url string.  However you still have a problem with your url because wherever you are constructing your url you are appending an object rather than a string to the end of it.

```
[object Object]
```

Is how javascript concatenates an object onto a string and clearly based on the error message the window is requesting a malformed url.